# Remove .0 from dataframe maintaining other numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with only a column that is an object type and contains a list of IDs. Each ID finishes with a .0 like this:

```
0442.0
0447.0
0461.0
0583.0
0612.0
```

Now i Would like to remove the final .0 maintaining the zeros to the left, like:

```
  0442
  0447
  0461
  0583
  0612
```

I already tried to apply .astype(int), but that causes me the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0442.0'
```

Then, I tried to perform the following modification:

```
df.astype(float).astype(int)
```

and that works but deletes the zeros to the left.
How can I remove only the .0 part?
Thank you very much

Comment: `df['col'].str.rstrip('.0')`?

Comment: `.str.replace('.0', '', regex=False)`?

Comment: What is type(df.iloc[0,0])?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `map` it string, `split` with `.` and grab the first part.

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.split('.').str[0]
```

Output:

```
    col
0   0442
1   0447
2   0461
3   0583
4   0612
```

Comment: Shouldn't need the `map(str)`.  These must be already strings, no numeric representation would keep the leading `0`

Comment: And if you did need to change to str, `.astype(str)` is more idiomatic.

Comment: Good catch @user3483203. Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your column is a string since there are leading 0s. So you need to replace the `.0` at the end:

```
df[0] = df[0].str.replace('\.0$', '')
                            # |
                            # Only changes `.0` at end. 0.01.0 -> 0.01
#      0
#0  0442
#1  0447
#2  0461
#3  0583
#4  0612
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda x: x.split('.')[0])
```